# maximum value from three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oledb

I have three tables which are as:

- table1(ID,JName, XVal, YVal)
- table2(ID, RName, XVAl, YVal)
- table3(ID, TName, XValue, YValue)

XValue, YValue , XVal, YVal are of number type. I want maximum and minimum value of XVal and YVal among all these tables. Previously I wrote following queries:

```
Select max(XVal) FROM table1
Select max(XVal) FROM table2
Select max(XValue) FROM table3
```

And for minimum value:

```
Select min(XVal) FROM table1
Select min(XVal) FROM table2
Select min(XValue) FROM table3
```

By running these queries, I can get 3 different results for minimum and maximum and then, I can just use logical codes to compare between them and get the maximum and minimum value but what i want here is single query which will do this for me.
I have used following queries:

```
Select max(XVal) from table1 UNION select max(XVal) from table2 UNION select max(XValue) as XVal from table3 ORDER BY 'MAX(XVal)'DESC LIMIT 1
```

And another one:

```
select max(XVal) as maxval from(select XVal from table1 UNION ALL SELECT XVal from table2 UNION ALL Select XValue from table3) as subquery
```

But both of them failed. Can somebody help me with this? And also point out the cause for the above queries to not function?

Comment: You second query looks good. Can you explain this *But both of them failed*

Comment: Erro: It says "Syntax error in order clause"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the first of the two versions is:

```
Select max(XVal) as max_XVal from table1 UNION ALL
select max(XVal) from table2 UNION ALL
select max(XValue) as XVal from table3
ORDER BY max_XVal DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can use either `UNION` or `UNION ALL` here.

If you want the minimum and maximum values from the three tables:

```
SELECT MIN(XVal), MAX(XVal)
FROM
(
    SELECT XVal FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT XVal FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT XVal FROM table3
) t123;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. your second query worked. First query returned an error: Syntax error in order clause

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` solution above is better but it's worth noting you could also just use your original query like this:

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST
    (
        (SELECT MAX(XVal) FROM table1),
        (SELECT MAX(XVal) FROM table2),
        (SELECT MAX(XValue) FROM table3)
    )
    LEAST
    (
        (SELECT MIN(XVal) FROM table1),
        (SELECT MIN(XVal) FROM table2),
        (SELECT MIN(XValue) FROM table3)
    )
```

Comment: an error occurs: undefined function 'greatest' in expression

Comment: Not sure why you'd be getting that unless you're not using MySQL.  `GREATEST()` is a standard MySQL function : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: I am not using mysql. I am working with [tag:oledb]. That would be why your query wasnot working for me.

Comment: @Skaranjit - Ok, that makes sense.  Your question is tagged **"MySQL"** so I figured this answer was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use a max over a subquery:

```
select max(val) from (
  select max(XVal) val from table1
  UNION ALL
  select max(XVal) from table2
  UNION ALL
  select max(XValue) from table3
) x
```

AFAIK this syntax will work all rbdms.